# Need (destitution) makes the strongest people foxlike

Tags: expressions, proverbs

I wonder if there is any English proverb alluding to this fact that destitution and poverty (generally 'need'), makes strongest and the most powerful people to act in a different (always negative) way?

For instance, I am sure at least many of us have heard some stories about moral people who once in the past had been totally chaste, faithful, reliable etc. and because of life pressure or out of need (poverty) get involved into dirty jobs and forcefully start acting as completely another (always negative) person.

I have heard a Kurdish and Dari (maybe Afghan or Persian languages) a similar proverb which says:

> برسێتی پشتی شێر دە شکێنێ

Translation:

> What makes the lions foxlike, is destitution.

In other words it says:

> Hunger will tame a lion.

I wonder if you could help me with it.

Comment: So, to clarify, are you asking for an idiom that describes people falling on hard times /adversity, turning into generally horrible people ?

Comment: As I mentioned @Smock at the beginning of my thread, I was looking for a **proverb** first of all. But as you know well, sometimes, there is an expression or idiom which can work instead of a proverb and convey the same message, especially when there is no proverbial equivalence for that concept. That was why I tagged my question with "idiom" and "expression" too.

Comment: Idiom/expression. I was asking to clarify the context & meaning, as that's  the bit that's not particularly clear to me. *foxlike* and *tame* are not similar :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly:

> "Necessity is the mother of invention"

It means, roughly, that the primary driving force for most new inventions is a need.

This is not *quite* the same as the meaning you allude to, namely that need/necessity makes people less moral, but does imply that it makes people think differently, perhaps more *practically*.

We also have the expression "*borne out of necessity*" which can describe *anything* created or done because it was necessary. To achieve your intended meaning you could say:

> His foxlike behaviour was borne out of necessity.

Your own saying in the title would be understood perfectly well, although I think that the word "strongest" is not the best choice. You seem to be trying to convey *moral* strength, not physical strength. Actually, what you need is an *antonym* of 'foxlike'. The quality usually associated with the fox is 'cunning', or being 'devious' or 'sly'. The word "honest" might be best:

> Need makes the honest man foxlike.

Comment: Thank you @Astralbee. Do my own translation work idiomatically in this sense? Do they sound natural and meaningful to you as a native speaker? To me your "Necessity is the mother of invention" means: "going through hard times can be so instructive and lead one towards higher positions and more prospor and success" which as you mentioned, it is not at all what I need

Comment: @A-friend I don't think the word "strongest" is what you need - without context that means physically strong, and I think what you mean is an antonym of 'foxlike'. Perhaps 'honest'??

Comment: *Desperate Times call for Desperate Measures*

Comment: But @Smock, AFAIC the proverbial sentence you provided us with (Desperate Times Call for Desperate Measures,) is only ussd when you mean that actions that might seem extreme under normal circumstances are appropriate during adversity; which is not at all what I need.

Comment: To me, that describe *moral people who once in the past had been totally chaste, faithful, reliable etc. and because of life pressure or out of need (poverty) get involved into dirty jobs and forcefully start acting as completely another (always negative) person.* perfectly

Comment: Thank you @Smock. Sounds great.